# A function to combine two arrays?

Tags: php

How to get array c from a and b ?

```
$arr_a = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => 1,
        'baz' => 2,
    ),
    'lorem' => array(
        'ipsum' => array(
            'dolor' => 'sit',
        ),
    ),  
    'mollis' => 'ultrices',
);
```

and the second array look like this:

```
$arr_b = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'ante' => 'urna'
    ),
    'lorem' => array(
        'ipsum' => array(
            'dolor' => 'turpis'
        ),
    ),
);
```

The result array should be:

```
$arr_c = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => 1,
        'baz' => 2,
        'ante' => 'urna',
    ),
    'lorem' => array(
        'ipsum' => array(
            'dolor' => 'turpis', 
        ),
    ),
    'mollis' => 'ultrices',  
);
```

I''ve tried `array_merge` but can't get a desirable result....
Cheers

```
$arr_c = array_merge_recursive($arr_a, $arr_b);
```

gives me an unwanted array - it's a bit tricky here:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => 1
            [baz] => 2
            [ante] => urna
        )

    [lorem] => Array
        (
            [ipsum] => Array
                (
                    [dolor] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => sit // unwanted :(
                            [1] => turpis
                        )

                )

        )

    [mollis] => ultrices
)
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Did you read up on http://us.php.net/array_merge ?

Answer (score 7):

I believe you're looking for the [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive) function.

```
$arr_c = array_merge_recursive($arr_a, $arr_b);
```

Comment: Thank you - it works but it doesn't create array C as in example - but I suppose it's the best answer

Answer (score 2):

This seems promising: [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).

Do a Google search, seriously.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr_c = array_merge($arr_a, $arr_b);
```

OR:

```
$arr_c = array_merge_recursive($arr_a, $arr_b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr_c = array_merge_recursive($arr_a, $arr_b);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple (see [CodePad as a proof](http://codepad.org/3RwlnY54)):

```
$arr_c = array_merge_recursive($arr_a, $arr_b);
```

See more documentation on [**`array_merge_recursive()`** PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).

Comment: array C should't have [0] => sit

Comment: @easyrider: Ok, so consider my answer as the answer to your **original** question. The new version of your question is not a simple merge case, you should probably create your own function.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
<?php
foreach($arr_b AS $key=>$val)
{
    if(array_key_exists($arr_a, $key)) $arr_a[$key][] = $val;
}
?>
```

Edit: And as I see I'm a bit too late and didn't know about array_merge_recursive :P